# Shopware 5.2.20. Cannot extend template via plugin

Tags: php, shopware

I'm trying to extend template `frontend/home/index.tpl` via own plugin.

Here my root file:

```
<?php
namespace TdevExtend;
use Shopware\Components\Plugin;
class TdevExtend extends Plugin
{
   public static function getSubscribedEvents(){
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Dispatcher_ControllerPath_Frontend_MyPlugin' =>
            'onDetailPostDispatch'
    ];
   }
   public function onDetailPostDispatch(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
   {
      $this->container->get('template')->addTemplateDir(
        $this->getPath() . '/Resources/views/'
      );
    return __DIR__ . '/Controllers/Frontend/MyPlugin.php';
   }
}
?>
```

Here are my Controller **MyPlugin.php** in dirrectory Controllers\Frontend

```
public function preDispatch()
   {
    /** @var \Shopware\Components\Plugin $plugin */
    $plugin = $this->get('kernel')->getPlugins()['TdevProductTab'];

    $this->get('template')->addTemplateDir($plugin->getPath() . '/Resources/views/');
}
```

And template in folder Resources\views\frontend\home\

```
 {extends file="parent:frontend/home/index.tpl"}
 {block name='frontend_index_content'}
    <div class="">Hello world!</div>
    {$smarty.block.parent}
 {/block}
```

I have read [official documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-system/) and researched plugins examples [plugins examples](https://github.com/shopware/devdocs)
After installing/reinstalling plugin crear cache on backend and delete manualy folder in `var/cache`. But nothing has helped me.

Comment: You will get what you want from the url https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/shopware-5-plugin-update-guide/#template-extensions

Comment: The link shows the old plugin system, but as far as I understand he is using the new plugin system.

Comment: Yes, i'm using new system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the Event `Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Index` in getSubscribedEvents instead of `Enlight_Controller_Dispatcher_ControllerPath_Frontend_MyPlugin`.

You are using the Event `Enlight_Controller_Dispatcher_ControllerPath_Frontend_MyPlugin`. When looking for controller `MyPlugin` Shopware will create this Event. So you need to write your own Controller when using this event. But I guess what you want is the event mentioned above. Actually you don't need to write a controller.

```
<?php
namespace TdevExtend;
use Shopware\Components\Plugin;
class TdevExtend extends Plugin
{
   public static function getSubscribedEvents(){
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Index' =>
            'onPostDispatch'
    ];
   }
   public function onPostDispatch(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
   {
      $this->container->get('Template')->addTemplateDir(
        $this->getPath() . '/Resources/views/'
      );
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello @Sadik. It doesn't work too.  Here is a link for [zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-uO_5Pl1EFBRGpWcnQ1QjRJaFU/view?usp=sharing) wit my plugin. Can you please check? May be some problems with template, because xdebug breakpoint works in `onPostDispatch`

Comment: The plugin in your zip file works perfectly well. Just put it into /custom/plugins folder. Remember that you have to reinstall the plugin after modifying.

Comment: What OS do you use? I'm using Windows and it still not working for me

Comment: Yes - a reason is server on Windows OS. On ubuntu all works fine

Comment: Is there is any solution to get it work on Windows OS ?