# Shopware 5: Plugin does not overwrite template view

Tags: php, shopware

Plugin has to overwrite the search template in Theme but it does not. It contains following files:
**PrOlgaStartup/PrOlgaStartup.php**

```
<?php

namespace PrOlgaStartup;

use Shopware\Components\Plugin;

class PrOlgaStartup extends Plugin
{

 public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
     return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend' => 'extendsFrontend'
    ];
}

public function extendsFrontend(\Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs $args)
{
    /** @var \Enlight_Controller_Action $controller */
    // Breadrcrumbs must dissapear
    $subject = $args->getSubject();
    $subject->View()->addTemplateDir(__DIR__ . '/Resources/views');

}
}
```

**PrOlgaStartup/Resources/views/frontend/index/search.tpl**

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/index/search.tpl"}

{block name="frontend_index_search_container"}
    Hello World!
{/block}
```

*Some Notes*

1. Tested in vagrant and bitnami
2. Theme is extended by `protected $injectBeforePlugins = true;`
3. Theme does not contain custom search.tpl
4. Cache has been cleared
5. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819695/shopware-5-2-20-cannot-extend-template-via-plugin) does not work as well

Thank you very much in advance!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make it work (i.e. include plugin templates) is:

1. Put the development environment into vagrant (I work on Windows OS)
2. Put variable `protected $injectBeforePlugins = true;` into Theme.php

The injection of this variable does not make any effect in bitnami at all, and the combination above seems to be missed in my tests. Why this is the case, it is not clear to me (now). Presumably, the only answer of the day is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819695/shopware-5-2-20-cannot-extend-template-via-plugin#comment72771135_42826390), i.e. it depends on your OS and/or on your virtual machine.

Comment: Consider marking this as the best answer, if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "new" way to register a template:

```
public function extendsFrontend(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
{
    $this->container->get('Template')->addTemplateDir(
        $this->getPath() . '/Resources/views/'
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Rotfuchs, thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, it has no effect... I mean am I only person who has this problem!?

Comment: I mean I do everything like [here](https://www.udemy.com/developer-training-basic/learn/v4/t/lecture/8869480?start=555) (begin at 7:00) (modulo PreDispatch), it does not work...

Comment: What exactly do you wan't to overwrite? The ajax-search has another template than the search-result page. Perhaps a Screenshot will help.
You should consider the hint with "injectbeforeplugins" too, because an overwrite via plugin is only possible, when there is no theme with injectbeforeplugins = false overwriting the same block.

Comment: Thank you, Rotfuchs, for the answer! I have already found the solution: see the answer below :-)